# I'm using medusajs and after updating "medusa-payment-razorpay" : "7.0.5-next-2", from "^7.0.1" I got stuck with an issue

Tags: razorpay, medusajs, medusa

Error:unanble to create customer An error occurred in initiatePayment when creating a Razorpay customerundefined

```
 medusa.carts.createPaymentSessions(cartId)
    .then(({ cart }) => {
    console.log(cart.id);
    })
```

I don't know how to solve it. The problem is that due to the error I am getting the data object empty and user cannot proceed further to pay without data object. Data object has the data of customer required for making the payment